# How to bring icons inside working area of tinymce?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Once i click on **image inside tinymce**. i need to display two **icon** on the **selected image**(edit,delete icons). once user click on **edit icon** on that image. i need to fetch selected **image attributes.**

Comment: it is not clear (to me) what you want to achieve here. are you talking about a right-click on an image inside tinymce and the opening contextmenu? where do you want to have the two icons? (i suspect you want them in the contextmenu)? what do you want those icons to do when clicked/choosen (if possible also post the code you use for that actions)?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. My requirement is to display edit, delete icon on the image once user select it. Then once user clicks edit icon i need to fetch imag tag attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the icons correctly you need to add css settings to the editor. To do this you need to use the tinymce setting [editor_css](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aeditor_css) :

```
editor_css : 'myserver.com/css/editor.css',
```

In order to make it work you need to specify where tinymce has to grab the images for the icaons you specify.
The content of `editor.css` should be something like

```
// make sure you use the right path to your images!!!

.defaultSkin span.mce_delete {background:url(../......../../images/delete.gif)} 
.defaultSkin span.mce_edit {background:url(../........../../images/edit.gif)}
```

Now you can specify the images for the icons in the contextmenu

```
if (typeof e !== "undefined" && e.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
th._menu.add({
    title: 'Delete',
    icon: 'delete', // here
    cmd: 'my_custom_command_delete'
});

m.add({
    title: 'Edit',
    icon: 'edit',  // here
    cmd: 'my_custom_command_edit'
});
```

Now we still do not have the commands set right, so onInit in our plugin we do:

```
  ed.addCommand('my_custom_command_delete', function() {
    // TODO place your code for that action here
  });

  ed.addCommand('my_custom_command_edit, function() {
    // TODO place your code for that action here
  });

enter code here
```

Comment: Thariama i changed my requirement. Dont consider context menu.

Comment: Once i click on image i need to display edit|delete icons on selected image. once i select edit icon i need to fetch all attributes of selected image. This is my requirement. Sorry if i didnt explained correctly

Comment: you need to display those icons on the image?

Comment: s I need to display icons on the image

Comment: hmm, you could try to make the contextmenu transparent and use an empty title

Comment: @Thariama on a click on image i need to display edit|delete image icon on particular image. Your answer helps me to bring contextmenu. i need to bring icons on image once user click image